# how to bind data to the dropdownlist on selected value of the other dropdownlist in asp.net?? I have already bind data to the all the dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, npgsql

//.aspx.cs code:

```
protected void ddldistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        ddltaluka.Enabled = true;
        string d1 = ddldistrict.Text;
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=*******;Database=guj_data;");
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT tname FROM taluka_geo_bnd_box WHERE district='"+d1+"'";
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        ds.Reset();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        ddltaluka.DataSource = ds;
        ddltaluka.DataTextField = "tname";
        ddltaluka.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
      }
    catch(Exception e3)
    {
        throw e3;
    }
}
protected void ddltaluka_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try { 
    ddlvillage.Enabled = true;
    string t1 = ddltaluka.Text;
    string d1 = ddldistrict.Text;
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=*****;Database=guj_data;");
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT vname FROM village_boundary_geo_bnd_box WHERE tname='"+t1+"' AND district='"+d1+"'";
    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

    ds.Reset();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    ddlvillage.DataSource = ds;
    ddlvillage.DataTextField = "vname";
    ddlvillage.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
  }
    catch(Exception e4)
    {
        throw e4;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Your title is insufficient explanation of your problem.  What problem are you hitting when you try to bind a fresh set of data based on the selection from the other dropdown?

Comment: @GiliusMaximus: the problem is when i try to bind the data on the selection of value from 'ddltaluka' dropdown, data from the 'ddlvillage' got erased after the method ddltaluka_selectedIndexChanged is called. And on 'pageload' i have already bind the data to the all the dropdown.

Comment: The answer is then what @JoeRaio said.  You only need to rebind the data for ddldistrict when it is not a postback.  If you rebind the data on the postback, the selection is lost and reset to the first item on the list.  Mind you, each time you go back to the code behind, for initial load of the page, or a postback from the same page, the page_load event is generated, first, so if you reload the data there, by the time you get to the selectedindexchanged event handler, you have lost that indexchanged event.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: And where is ds coming from?  Is that a global ?  Are you binding the lists to it but then resetting it on each event handler?  You show the event handlers for two dropdowns selectedindexchanged events, but nothing of the page-load, nothing of maybe a third dropdown you have, nothing of the html, no verbal description of the problem.  This is an extremely insufficient post.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly;
ddlvillage data bind happens at page load
when the method ddltaluka_selectedIndexChanged is called, you try to bind new data do it but it goes back to the original ddlVillage list?

If this is the case you need to only do the initial databind for ddlVillage on the initial page load and not each post back

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
       //bind your initial data here

  }
```

Comment: hello sir, now after you advised i tried it in a same way but now when the ddltaluka_selectedIndexchanged method is called it takes the first value from the dropdown and display the village value in the ddlvillage dropdown.